# Nested Quantifiers Proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, quantifiers

Trying to wrap my head around how to prove something like this:

$$\exists x \in\Bbb R~, \forall y \in\Bbb R:(y \geqslant x) \lor [y \in (-\infty, -1) \cup (1, +\infty)]$$

Comment: y ∈ (-∞, -1) ∨ (1, +∞) does not make sense. Do you mean $y\in(-\infty,-1)\cup(1,+\infty)$ ?

Comment: Yes, sorry wrote that in wrong

Answer (score 1):

Is true.

Take $x = -1$

Then if $y ≥ x = -1$ we are done. Else $y<x = -1 \implies y \in (-\infty, -1)$

So the condition its holds.

Comment: In other words, with a little equivalence exchange we find an example $x$ which witnesses: $$\exists x{\in}\Bbb R~,\forall y{\in}\Bbb R: ((y< x)\to (y< -1\lor y>1))$$